# Creating user's home folder before account creation

Tags: c#, windows, user-profile

I have a C# program that checks some application config files that are store in a user's home folder (ex. C:\Users\username\AppData\someconfig.txt). If the path or file doesn't exist then it creates it.

Windows normally names the user folder as C:\Users\username the first time a user account is logged in, but if that folder already exsits then it creates it as C:\Users\username.computername instead.

I would like Windows to use the folder that my application created as the home folder so that I don't have to log into every new users account before I run my application.

Any Ideas would be helpful.

Comment: If you're using Active Directory take a look at [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732253(v=ws.11).aspx). Then you just have to find out how to do that programmatically.

Comment: I am not using AD. I tried this guide for setting a local user's home folder, but it still create a different home folder when I logged in.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/816313/how-to-assign-a-home-folder-to-a-user

Comment: I found [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/816313/how-to-assign-a-home-folder-to-a-user). I haven't read it by I believe it doesn't involve AD.

Comment: @dcg, both the articles you link to are about the user's network home directory.  The OP is asking about the user's profile, or more specifically the user's Application Data folder.  Not the same thing.